# Online calculator for linear algebra complete solution to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, calculator

Looking for an **online calculator** that can provide the complete solution to a system of linear equations $Ax= b$ (given matrix $A_{m\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb R^m$) as a self-study resource for my linear algebra students. For example where one could input the augmented matrix
$$\verb+input:   +\left[A\,|\,b\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
2&4&3&7&-1&-7\\
{1}&2&2&5&3&6\\
-3&-6&-1&0&1&2
\end{array}\right]
$$
then receive the RREF form after elimination such as
$$\verb+output:   +\left[R\,|\,d\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
\fbox{1}&2&0&-1&0&1\\
0&0&\fbox{1}&3&0&-2\\
0&0&0&0&\fbox{1}&3
\end{array}\right]
$$
and finally the complete solution as the particular solution plus any linear combination of the special solutions (i.e. $N(A)$) as
$\newcommand{bm}[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}$
$$\verb+output:   +x\ = \ \bm{1\\0\\-2\\0\\3} + c_1\bm{-2\\1\\0\\0\\0} + c_2\bm{1\\0\\-3\\1\\0}, \quad (c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R).
$$
The online calculators I found can only fulfill some of these functions, for example the [RREF calculator](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-algebra/gauss-jordan-elimination-calculator/?i=%5B%5B2%2C4%2C3%2C7%2C-1%2C-7%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C3%2C6%5D%2C%5B-3%2C-6%2C-1%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D%5D&reduced=on) or the [special solutions calculator](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-algebra/null-space-calculator/?i=%5B%5B2%2C4%2C3%2C7%2C-1%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C3%5D%2C%5B-3%2C-6%2C-1%2C0%2C1%5D%5D) but I am yet to find one for the complete solution. If the calculator could show the elimination process with the row operations that would be nice too.

Comment: @Steve Please be explicit about what you feel is missing from the emath calculators, because it looks like those two pages address all of your concerns

Comment: It's behind a paywall, but WolframAlpha offers steps for both [RREF](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=rref+%7B%7B2%2C4%2C3%2C7%2C-1%2C-7%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C3%2C6%7D%2C+%7B-3%2C-6%2C-1%2C0%2C1%2C2%7D%7D) (even including a step that highlights the pivots as in your $[R\mid d]$ matrix) and [nullspace](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=nullspace+%7B%7B2%2C4%2C3%2C7%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C3%7D%2C+%7B-3%2C-6%2C-1%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)

Comment: To me SageMath seems a good FOSS option (however it's a CAS rather than just a calculator), and there are some [online](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) [interpreters](https://cocalc.com/?utm_source=sagemath.org&utm_medium=top).

Comment: @Moo and BenGrossman: The particular solution isn't included in either.